# How can I find the Quake room?

Tags: rage, quake

In addition to the Doom room and the Wolfenstein room, I have also heard that there is a secret level as a homage to id Software's game Quake.

Where can I find this level and what do I need to do in order to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the Quake level, you will need to search the Wasted Garage for three hidden buttons. It is recommended not to attempt to find these buttons while completing the mission to collect parts for your buggy, due to the number of enemies in the level.

The buttons do not have an on screen prompt, but you will know when they've been activated as they make a Quake-like sound when pressed.

- The first button is on the second floor, near where you had previously found the distrbutor cap for your buggy, underneath some drawers
- The second button is on the third floor, in a small room behind a filing cabinet - facing the wall. You will need to press against the wall and crouch in order to reach the button
- The final button is on the fourth floor, to the left of the red workbench
- The entrance level is back on the second floor. In one of the deadend hallways you can find a Quake "Q" painted on one of the walls - run up the steps and enter the portal to get to the level

Here is a youtube video detailing where to find these buttons and the entrance to the hidden room: